# assigns(:var).should_receive(:method) in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to set up the controller test to confirm that one of my instance variables  (`@template`) receives a given function call (`deliver`).

With the following code, however, the `assigns` gets evaluated before the `posts`, so `assigns` is `nil`:

```
  it 'calls @template.deliver' do
    assigns(:template).should_receive(:deliver).and_call_original
    post :deliver, params
  end
```

How can I set up this test effectively?

*Tech stack:

Ruby 1.9.3p448

Rails 3.2.13

rspec-rails 2.13.1 (for the accepted answer below, I had to upgrade to 2.14)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `@template` is an instance of a `Template` object, you may be able to use rspecs expect syntax:

```
it 'calls @template.deliver' do
  Template.any_instance.stub(deliver: true)

  post :deliver, params

  expect(assigns(:template)).to have_received(:deliver)
end
```

Comment: I get "undefined method `has_received?'" Is `have_received` implemented in a later RSpec than what I have posted in my tech stack above?

Comment: @JellicleCat it's `have_received ` not `has_received ` but yes - I believe this was introduced in 2.14 - sorry for not noticing your stack.

Comment: I know it's `have_received`. The error message refers to `has_received?`, however. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest seems to create your template object upfront, and then stub the Template.find method to return the object you've created, something like (using mocha in my case)

```
@template = ...
Template.stubs(:find).returns(@template)
```

You can then use the statement you've written like

```
@template.should_receive(:deliver).and_call_original
```

Answer (score 0):

One way i can think of is stubbing the part that assigns template

For eg(Assuming that you have a separate test for get_template):

If you have the following deliver action

```
def deliver
  @template = get_template
  @template.deliver
end
```

And your test can be

```
it 'calls @template.deliver' do
  controller.should_receive(:get_template).and_return(mock_template = mock("template"))
  mock_template.should_receive(:deliver).and_call_original
  post :deliver, params
end
```